# Buscar por titulo o custom field wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Tengo creadas varias páginas con su respectivo título y demás ¿No?. Aparte, cada una de ellas tiene un custom field llamado: "color" y puede tener un valor cualquiera.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo retornar en un PHP todos los resultados de las páginas que coincidan cuando buscan por su título o por el valor del custom field "color"?. Pongo un ejemplo:

**Titulo página**  y **color**

Nuevo coche Seat - rojo
Coche Seat león - Amarillo
Coche Audi 1234 - Arbol

Necesito retornar, por ejemplo, "Coche seat león" si alguien en el buscador ha puesto: "coche" o "seat" o "coche león" y "amarillo". ¿Me doy a entender?. Se puede buscar por titulo o por titulo y color o solo por color. son campos opcionales. El valor "color" es un select por si eso sirve de algo.

Muchísimas gracias

Un saludo,
Ángel.